# How to inject dependencies into a dynamic list of objects in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a list of objects that can change dynamically. How can I inject dependencies into these objects? If they were components (created using `*ngFor`) then `@Inject(...)` on constructor works out of the box.

But I don't need these objects to appear in the DOM. So can I e.g. get a list of Service instances instead of Component instances out of a list of object (similar to `*ngFor`, but for services)?

For example, I want the game component to run `update()` on every item object:

```
@Component
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.css']
})
export class GameComponent {
    private items : Item[] = [
        ... // just some arbitrary test data for now
    ];

    ...

    private update() {
        for (item of items) {
            item.update(); // want to run some logic on each item
        }
    }
}
```

However to implement `item.update()`, I would need to inject the `DatabaseService`, which I can't because the item list is not managed by Angular. I could instead implement the update function in another Service class, but then the update function would require a reference to the item, e.g.:

GameComponent's modified `update()` function:

```
    private update() {
        for (item of items) {
            itemService.update(item); // want to run some logic on each item
        }
    }
```

The `update()` function of the `Item` class would be moved to `ItemService`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(DatabaseService) private db : DatabaseService
    ) { }

    update(item : Item) {
        ... // implementation moved to here
    }
}
```

This works for now, but if I am going to implement many more functions in the `Item` class in the future, I find this pattern not so object oriented, e.g. I cannot inherit Item class and override the `update()` function.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Well, when you create the instances of Item, pass the DatabaseService as argument to their constructor.

Comment: Aha, that sounds better than what I'm doing now :D . Although I think the point of dependency injection is to avoid having to pass the dependencies ourselves. Importantly, the `GameComponent` doesn't need to know that Item needs `DatabaseService`, so if the Item object needs more dependencies we don't need to change GameComponent (and all other classes in the structure if the code gets bigger).

Comment: Well, delegate the creation of the items to a service, which receives the necessary dependencies and passes them to the Item constructor. In short, a factory.

Comment: Thanks!!! I gotta try that but sounds like it must work :)) . I want to accept that as the answer

Comment: @VincentiusKevin it not better - its the exact same thing - the difference is in WHO is organizind dependencies - either injected by DependencyInjector or passed as argument by you - same implementation in both cases.

Comment: I think it is better. For example, AComponent contains BComponent as its child, and BComponent contains CComponent as its child. If a service is provided by AComponent, CComponent can use it (with @Inject) even if BComponent never knows about the service. With the factory solution, I still need to provide the service to the item constructor, but I don't need to pass the service over from A to B to C.

Comment: @Antoniossss Now I see your point :( . I saved the hassle of going from A to C but then C is not managed and hence cannot provide a scope, i.e. I can't make Item provide a certain service that is scoped only under that Item instance and not shared with any other Item instance.

I wonder if there is a function to inject an object given a certain scope. E.g. Angular.inject(item, cComponent), which means to inject the Item with all dependencies provided by CComponent or its parents.